# Is it possible to change a specific footer tag out of multiple, without changing the HTML code?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently studying web development and I'm in a rough patch. We have been given an assignment where we are supposed to design a HTML code without changing it at all.

My question is, is there anyway too style a specific footer (**bottom one**) tag (that's not inside of a another tag, for example, a div tag, too make it even more difficult) of the HTML code in CSS without changing anything in the HTML code?

```html
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>Modul 2 - uppgift 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stil.css"> 
  </head> 
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper"> 
      <header>
        <h1></h1>
      </header> 
      <article> 
        <section> 
          <header>
            <h2>Om CSS</h2>
          </header> 
          <p> .</p> 
          <p></p> 
          <p class="linktext"></p>
          <footer></footer> 
        </section> 
        <section> 
          <header>
            <h2></h2>
          </header>
          <p></p>
          <p>.</p> 
          <p class="linktext"></p> 
          <footer></footer> 
        </section> 
      </article>
      <footer></footer> 
    </div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

I've been trying to solve this myself and tried to do some research with no results that's why i came here. The teacher doesn't really help out with questions like these either...

I hope i made the question clear, maybe the reason I cant find anything online because of the way I'm phrasing it, let me know! and thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey mate, can you pls share your html and maybe desired result , so we can try to help you, cheers :)

Comment: No problem, I added it for you, you can add code in snippet or in Code Sample in your question. OK what footer do you need to style?

Comment: Thank you so much i appreciate it! I'm trying too style the bottom one without changing the code.

but in theory, i could easily do that by wrapping the footer in a div tag right?

Comment: Yes you can , take a look at @LattyS answer, that is a way to style your elements without touching html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select last `footer` with `:nth-child` pseudo class.
Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) please

```css
#wrapper > footer {
  color: red;
  font-style: italic;
}
/*
OR
#wrapper footer:nth-child(4) {
  color: red;
  font-style: italic;
}*/
```

```html
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>Modul 2 - uppgift 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stil.css"> 
  </head> 
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper"> 
      <header>
        <h1></h1>
      </header> 
      <article> 
        <section> 
          <header>
            <h2>Om CSS</h2>
          </header> 
          <p> .</p> 
          <p></p> 
          <p class="linktext"></p>
          <footer>first footer</footer> 
        </section> 
        <section> 
          <header>
            <h2></h2>
          </header>
          <p></p>
          <p>.</p> 
          <p class="linktext"></p> 
          <footer>second footer</footer> 
        </section> 
      </article>
      <aside>
      </aside>
      <footer>last footer</footer> 
    </div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Hmm, tried this out and it makes all of the footers colored for some reason, but this pseudo class is something i will definitely keep in mind, as it can come in handy! Appreciate it!

Comment: I think I did it right? https://gyazo.com/c940812974976e9113ecbb91df5fc8c3 here is a picture of the code (for referencing better) showing that all the footers turn red, even though the one with the text "Hermods" is the last footer. I assume im doing something wrong here?

Comment: Sorry mate, my bad take a look now, I updated answer

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work either, I still Believe I'm doing something wrong here... This is the code including the CSS in its entirely (text and everything, but all in swedish) incase it's helps https://gyazo.com/ae70b0aa91483000f37020add8eb0262 
https://gyazo.com/b747c8251e00ae205b381d7a5557de83

Comment: Ahh, that's because of `aside` tag(you didn't provide that), you need to set 4 instead of 3  `#wrapper footer:nth-child(4)`

Comment: That made everything work out perfectly! Thank you so much for real, I can't express how much I appreciated all the help from you!

Comment: @JayBerg this is not a robust solution, you may end selecting the footer inside section. Use `#wrapper > footer {}` instead

Comment: @Temani Afif hey mate you are right (as always) :), my motto: why simply when it can be complicated :) cheers

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif I will make sure I keep this in mind!

Answer (score 1):

I think you shoul have a look at the css [Child combinator (>)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) and the [:nth-child() pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

For example if you want to select the third div in your footer:

```
<footer>
  <div>Lorem ipsum 1</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum 2</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum 3</div>
</footer>
```

And the css:

```
footer div:nth-child(3) {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna make sure i read through this and try to make something work out of it! Appreciate the help from you both Latty and @NikolaPavicevic